# Check if user has logged in before displaying content

Tags: php

I am new in coding server side with PHP and have made a simple hardcoded login. I want to make sure that the user has logged in from `memberLogin.html` before they can view the items in `memberPage.html` so that if in the browser they type in the `URL/memberPage.php`, they are redirected to `memberLogin.html` to first login. Currently, logging in from **memberLogin.html** works correctly but I can still view the contents of **memberPage.php** without logging in by typing the `URL/memberPage.php` in the browser.

Here is the code I have used:
**memberLogin.html**

```
<form name="memberLogin" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="memberLoginSubmit.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="usr">Username:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="username" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**memberLoginSubmit.php**

```
  $username = "";
  $password = "";
  if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];
  }

  $usr = "123";
  $pwd = "123";
  $invalidLogin = 'Incorrect Username and/or Password. Please try again.';

  if ($password == $pwd && $username == $usr){
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
      header('Location: memberPage.php');
  }else{
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
      echo 'alert("Incorrect Username and/or Password. Please try again.");';
      echo 'window.location.href = "memberLogin.html";';
      echo '</script>';
  }
```

**memberPage.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] != true){
        header('memberLogin.html');
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Rest of the HTML code--!>
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: @memberPage.php - just remove the require 'memberLoginSubmit.php' and then change your condition to just: if (!$_SESSION['loggedin']){ header('memberLogin.html'); }

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']` exist before using them

**memberLoginSubmit.php**

```
 $username = "";
 $password = "";
 if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
 }

 // ...
```

You can do it with `isset()` too

Comment: I added this and removed `require 'memberLoginSubmit.php';` in **memberPage.php** and now logging in from **memberLogin.html** works however I can still type in the `URL/memberPage.php` and it displays the contents of that page without logging in.

Comment: @AnhadJangra you surely did an error with the use of `$_SESSION['loggedin']`, maybe you let it as `true` or the condition isn't good, in **memberPage.php** try to redirect the user on the login page if the session is false

Answer (score 0):

I think your code just needs a little improvement. Try adding these things:
Try adding a new variable called passwordEntered, another one called memberPassword, then follow these steps:

1. Add some code so you can get the password the user entered, then set `passwordEntered` to that.
2. Compare `passwordEntered` to `memberPassword`.
3. If `memberPassword` is equal to `passwordEntered`, then user is logged in. If not, access is denied.

Try and see if it works. If not, just reply to this comment and then I will help you find another solution. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to rewrite `require 'memberLoginSubmit.php';` in memberPage.php to check user login. You just need to check the SESSION

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] != true){
    header('memberLogin.html');
}
```